# Capture Dolby Atmos 5.1 from Apple Music

Tags: macos, itunes, audio, music, monterey

A few Dolby Atmos version of tracks I listen to sound weird. I want to inspect what is going on and compare it to the stereo mix. However, the Dolby Atmos version is only available on Apple Music, which means I cannot download it and open it in Audition, for example.

I tried to capture the audio using Blackhole 2ch, 6ch (5.1), and 8ch (7.1), but Apple Music always output 2-channel only. How can I get Apple Music to output 5.1 or 7.1 into blackhole?

Answer (score 0):

Atmos, like most domestic surround formats, is encoded within a stereo signal, rather than as discrete channels. To separate it out, you need a decoder. Because of some <strike>draconian</strike> licensing laws, this tends to be a 'last point in the chain' process, so trying to intercept the signal on the way doesn't work.

You could see if [Dolby's conversion tool](https://professional.dolby.com/product/dolby-atmos-content-creation/dolby-atmos-conversion-tool/) can see it for what it is.
I haven't tried it myself, but I've been fighting this issue for over a decade [initially on Windows, more recently on Mac], attempting to pre-process 5.1 inside a computer before onward transmission to a dedicated 5.1 AVR. This was even with dedicated 5.1-capable pro-audio plugins.
For background, see [Sound Design - Mac Pro 3,1 - true 5.1 control over outputs?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/45949/mac-pro-3-1-true-5-1-control-over-outputs)

<sup>Since writing that QA, I have changed the Mac to a Mac Pro 5,1 & bought a new, more comprehensive, AVR. As a consequence I am now transmitting sound over HDMI to the AVR rather than S/PDIF as before. This actually provides a better decode solution after I insert my stereo-only compressors in the chain.</sup>

Comment: From what I've read, Atmos Digital Plus / E-AC-3, which is what Apple should be using, is encoded as 5.1 + sideband metadata. When decoded, the sideband metadata is used to reconstruct the object clusters, which is then rendered (downmixed) to the output configuration. Could you please explain more why Atmos is stereo in Apple Music?

Comment: E.g. when I decode E-AC-3 in Audition, that gives me 6 (5+1) channels. That's downloaded from Tidal. If I select AC-4 as the format to download, then I get stereo IMS in Dolby Reference Player.

Comment: I can't do better than 'because it is' the same as all other multichannel consumer audio. It's decoded at the final hardware. If you try to sniff it on the way, as 'true' audio, there's a chance that you will lose the metadata, but I haven't tested this. Personally I think Atmos is like quad in the 70s… fun for 5 minutes.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused because I can clearly see 6 channels if I decode an EAC3 file. Unfortunately I can't do that with Apple Music since DRM so I have to record the audio. I guess my question is can I force Apple Music to output 5.1. I think you did get VLC to output 5.1 though, or did you?

Comment: Apple Music already have a built-in decoder and renderer, so decoding is not a problem. The problem is with the renderer, which have no configurations I / the user can change.

Comment: And also Dolby's conversion tool only works on master formats. I'm asking a few artists/labels for them (ADM BWF) but it's pretty much 100% guaranteed failure. If I had access to that I won't need Apple Music anymore.

Comment: You seem to be at about the level of incredulity I was when investigating the 5.1 outputs on the Mac. "How come I can easily make my own 5.1 tracks, but I can't simply intercept existing ones the same way?" I even own a full suite of 5.1 capable VST/AUs I could use… but they only see stereo. I can decode a file manually, I just can't properly intercept one on the fly, as an audio stream. I wasn't even fighting DRM at the time.